# transposing rows into columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe track_log where columns are

```
item  track_info  Date    
----------------------
1     ordered     01/01/19
1     Shipped     02/01/19
1     delivered   03/01/19
```

I want to get data as

```
 item       ordered    Shipped    Delivered
--------------------------------------------
  1        01/01/19   02/01/19   03/01/19
```

need to resolve this using pyspark

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a solution like this:

```
>>> df.show()
+----+----------+--------+
|item|track_info|    date|
+----+----------+--------+
|   1|   ordered|01/01/19|
|   1|   Shipped|02/01/19|
|   1| delivered|03/01/19|
+----+----------+--------+
>>> df_grouped=df.groupBy(df.item).agg(collect_list(df.track_info).alias('grouped_data'))
>>> df_grouped_date=df.groupBy(df.item).agg(collect_list(df.date).alias('grouped_dates'))
>>> df_cols=df_grouped.select(df_grouped.grouped_data).first()['grouped_data'].insert(0,'item')
>>> df_grouped_date.select(df_grouped_date.item,df_grouped_date.grouped_dates[0],df_grouped_date.grouped_dates[1],df_grouped_date.grouped_dates[2]).toDF(*df_cols).show()
+----+--------+--------+---------+
|item| ordered| Shipped|delivered|
+----+--------+--------+---------+
|   1|01/01/19|02/01/19| 03/01/19|
+----+--------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi Jim, Tried the above code but there are 2more keys along with item so getting typeerror: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments given 4

Comment: You can insert how many ever you want with one more. insert(index_of_insert,value_to_be _inserted).

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark pivot function to do that as a single liner as below

```
>>> df.show()
+----+----------+--------+
|item|track_info|    date|
+----+----------+--------+
|   1|   ordered|01/01/19|
|   1|   Shipped|02/01/19|
|   1| delivered|03/01/19|
+----+----------+--------+
>>> pivot_df  = df.groupBy('item').pivot('track_info').agg(collect_list('date'))
>>> pivot_df.show()
+----+--------+--------+---------+
|item| ordered| Shipped|delivered|
+----+--------+--------+---------+
|   1|[01/01/19]|[02/01/19]| [03/01/19]|
+----+--------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi Aru, I'm getting an error that collec_list takes exactly 1 argument.. So do i need to this multiple times. as there are 27 such arguments

Comment: Corrected typo , @satish I am getting, please share the script or error